# Fedora automount external hdd where can I change the mount options

Tags: fedora, hard-disk, automounting

I've been pulling my hair to know where I configure the auto mount configurations for when I plug in my external harddrive.
As I really don't want to have atime changed when I have my external hdd.

I've been using Fedora 26 and I need to know the location of configuration files to allow me to edit the rules for mount options.

Comment: Look at the systemd.automount man pages.

Comment: don_crissti, slm: This is clearly not really a duplicate of the linked answer, as the answer doesn't work for fedora 25/26/27 and not even Ubuntu.
Raman Sailopal: I will look at those, I appreciate your comment.